# How to update entire object in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am trying to update the particular student details here based on the student id.I don't know how to update the entire student details using findById.
I am able to get the updated values from the frontend and send it to the server but from server i can able to send the updated values to the mongoDB but there i don't know how to update. 
Please help me out.

this is my server code:

```
server.post('/update',urlencodedParser,function(req,res){
var response={
  Id:req.body.Id,
  Fname : req.body.Fname,
  age:req.body.age,
  Lname : req.body.Lname,
  dob : req.body.dob,
  pob : req.body.pob,
  month : req.body.month,
  nation : req.body.nation,
  mothertongue : req.body.mothertongue,
  bloodgroup : req.body.bloodgroup,
  fatherfname : req.body.fatherfname,
  fatherlname : req.body.fatherlname,
  occupation : req.body.occupation,
  placeofwork : req.body.placeofwork,
  officaladd : req.body.officaladd,
  emailid : req.body.emailid,
  phoneno : req.body.phoneno,
  mobileno : req.body.mobileno,
  motherfname : req.body.motherfname,
  motherlname : req.body.motherlname,
  motheroccupation : req.body.motheroccupation,
  motherplaceofwork : req.body.motherplaceofwork,
  motherofficaladd : req.body.motherofficaladd,
  motheremailid : req.body.motheremailid,
  motherphoneno : req.body.motherphoneno,
  mothermobileno : req.body.mothermobileno,
  adress : req.body.adress,
  emergencyadress : req.body.emergencyadress,
  emergencyphone1 : req.body.emergencyphone1,
  emergencyphone2 : req.body.emergencyphone2,
  relationship1 : req.body.relationship1,
  relationship2 : req.body.relationship2

}
databaseInterface.updateStudent(response,  function(err, valss){
  if(err) res.send('ERROR!');
  console.log(valss);
  res.send(valss);
})
})
```

this is my mongoose code :

```
function updateStudent(response,callback) {
  console.log(response)
    User.findById(response.Id, function(err, studentcollection2) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
            studentcollection2 = response;
        return callback(null, studentcollection2);
         });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer i have came up with.

```
   function updateStudent(response,callback) {
      console.log(response.Id)
      User.update({'Id':response.Id}, {$set:{
      'Firstname':response.Fname,
      'Age' : response.age,
      'Lastname' : response.Lname,
      'DateOfBirth' : response.dob,
      'PlaceOfBirth' : response.pob,
      'Months' : response.month,
      'Nationality' : response.nation,
      'MotherTongue' : response.mothertongue,
      'BloodGroup' : response.bloodgroup,
      'Father.Firstname' : response.fatherfname,
      'Father.Lastname' : response.fatherlname,
      'Father.Occupation' : response.occupation,
      'Father.PlaceOfWork' : response.placeofwork,
      'Father.OfficialAddress' : response.officaladd,
      'Father.EmailId' : response.emailid,
      'Father.PhoneNo' : response.phoneno,
      'Father.MobileNo' : response.mobileno,
      'Mother.Firstname' : response.motherfname,
      'Mother.Lastname' : response.motherlname,
      'Mother.Occupation' : response.motheroccupation,
      'Mother.PlaceOfWork' : response.motherplaceofwork,
      'Mother.OfficialAddress' : response.motherofficaladd,
      'Mother.EmailId' : response.motheremailid,
      'Mother.PhoneNo' : response.motherphoneno,
      'Mother.MobileNo' : response.mothermobileno,
      'ResidentialAddress' :response.adress,
      'EmergencyContactNumber.Address' : response.emergencyadress,
      'EmergencyContactNumber.PhoneNo1' : response.emergencyphone1,
      'EmergencyContactNumber.PhoneNo2' : response.emergencyphone2,
      'EmergencyContactNumber.Relationship1' : response.relationship1,
      'EmergencyContactNumber.Relationship2' : response.relationship2
            }
        }, function(err, studentcollection2) {
          console.log(studentcollection2);
            if (err) return callback(err);
            return callback(null, 'success');
             });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose provides a specific function to find and update. The main thin you are missing is the {$set: response}. Mongoose will replace every value in the stored ID with the respective value from response. Just make sure that your Mongoose Schema for User will allow all of these. The second part of your code should be like this:

```
function updateStudent(response,callback) {
  console.log(response)
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(response.Id, {$set:response},function(err, studentcollection2) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        return callback(null, 'success');
         });
    }
```

Comment: It's returning undefined. And i am getting ERORR! as response

Comment: Is req.body.Id equivalent to the id stored in Mongodb (the id used for indexing, 24 characters long)?

Comment: And i have make sure that the custom id is reaching the mongoose.

Comment: Thanks your answer gave some clues to my question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to update the entire document without needing to specify each field is the following:

```html
<FUNCTION_NAME>: async (req, res, next) => {
    await <YOUR_MODEL>.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            _id: <ID_PARAMETER>,
          },
          {
            ...req.body,
          },
          { new: true },
        );
  },
```

You might add a try catch and other things, but I wanted to show the clear east way!